# Can't install ProxyGenerator from scholary

Tags: web-scraping, proxy, web-crawler, citations

I know google scholarly is blocking my request to get citation. The workaround suggested by the scholarly package's author is to use proxies - https://pypi.org/project/scholarly/. But I tried to follow the procedure start importing the  `from scholarly import scholarly, ProxyGenerator` and I get the error attached. I went to the scholarly file in site package and I could not find it. How do i resolve this problem?

[error received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyDoG.png)